# 何でもきいてください in an interview

Tags: grammar

I have a Question -> Response exercise in my textbook. The context is a job interview at a convenience store. The final question from the store manager is below and I think he/she is saying "Well then, finally, about the convenience store work please ask anything you like"

Can somebody translate this for me please? Or confirm I am right?

```
それでは最後にコンビニの仕事について何でもきいてください
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. Your version is perfectly OK as a first-stage translation. But if you were translating this as part of a film script, say, and were trying to achieve natural-sounding dialogue, you might consider something like "And finally, is there anything you'd like to ask me about working in a convenience store?"

Comment: Thanks Graham, I just wanted to make sure I was right before I commit this to memory.